# Database connection not closing when using multiple contexts

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, h2

We have two H2 in-memory databases that we connect to for testing. To do this we originally had one context.xml file containing the information to connect to each database and this worked correctly.

Now we have to split the context.xml file out so there are two context files as we would like to close one context while keeping the other open.

The problem is that now after separating these out and creating two individual ClassPathXmlApplicationContext objects when running tests data is persisting between the tests. This originally worked when using one context, closing it, and creating a new context. Now these are separated out and closing both contexts isn't removing all connections to the database. This then means that H2 doesn't create a new database.

The last few days I've been looking around and I can't find any information on any similar cases.

This is used for the database urls to set it to use an in-memory database:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:db1;
jdbc:h2:mem:db2;
```

A simplified version of our Services file:

```
public static Provider1 getProvider1() {
    if (SERVICE_1 == null) {
        initialise1();
    }
    return SERVICE_1;
}

public static Provider2 getProvider2() {
    if (SERVICE_2 == null) {
        initialise2();
    }
    return SERVICE_2;
}

private static void initialise1() {
    try {
        CONTEXT_1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/Context1.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    } catch (BeanCreationException ex) {

    }

    SERVICE_1 = CONTEXT_1.getBean(Provider1.class);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (CONTEXT_1 != null) {
                CONTEXT_1.close();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void initialise2() {
    try {
        CONTEXT_2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/Context2.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    } catch (BeanCreationException ex) {

    }

    SERVICE_2 = CONTEXT_2.getBean(Provider2.class);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (CONTEXT_2 != null) {
                CONTEXT_2.close();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void shutDown(){

    CONTEXT_1.close();
    CONTEXT_2.close();

    SERVICE_1 = null;
    SERVICE_2 = null;
}
```

In the test method the initialise `shutdown` method is called and then `getProvider1`. This should close both connections to the databases but in the next test method it has data from the previous test. I understand there should be a separate `initialise` and `shutdown` method for each context but this is okay for an example.

If any other information is needed let me know. I've tried recreating this on a small scale but I'm unable to. Any ideas that could help me work this out would be perfect as it is quite unusual.

What could be some likely causes for this?

Comment: It's a problem about connections or about data?

Comment: Connections. For H2 to create a new database all connections to the current database need to be closed. In this case it isn't closing all connections. This causes the next test case to create a connection to the already existing database.

Comment: You are loading everything in the same JVM/classloaders etc. Both contexts use the same JDBC url and as such actually share the same database. You would need to separate those URLs per context. Another things is that there is even a change that you end up with 4 contexts if you call those 2 methods in parallel. IN short your code looks (and probably is) dangerous and basically an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the other database url. I've updated my question. 
In terms of calling the methods in parallel, the code I've uploaded has the contexts being created together. This is just for the example as in my actual code I have separate methods for creating the contexts. I've separated them out and updated my question for this now.